# OP177 supply voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to use OP177 with 2s lithium batteries (in series) so my voltage range is +/-3.3 V to +/-4 V however I cannot find anything related to minimum supply voltage on the [datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/op177.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjmlO6FlJP2AhURrqQKHeXqALAQFnoECBwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0B01COCY8V4EqvaOCG9bXb) or anywhere else online. What is minimum supply voltage for OP177?

Note: please see also this related question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609557/peak-detector-for-microcontroller).

Comment: The minimum supply voltage is dependent on what tasks you want the op-amp to do and in which kind of circuit and what input and output voltages are required to do the task. Without this information nobody can answer you question, except that the supplies typically might need to be higher by 2-3 volts than what voltages you intend to apply to inputs or expect to see on outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a hint that the minimum supply is around 6 volts: -

[image]

And, if you look above those highlighted you'll see that the guaranteed input voltage range is +/- 13 volts on a +/- 15 volts rail - this gives clues about how it would perform at +/- 3 volts on the rails - the input would be restricted to a usable range of +/- 1 volts.

The output would be restricted to a range of +/-1.5 volts on a +/- 3 volt rail.

> *I need to use OP177 with 2s lithium batteries (in series) so my
> voltage range is +-3.3v to +-4v*

It will operate but, if you are looking for anything close to rail-to-rail performance then you should look for a different op-amp.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the guaranteed specifications are only with +/-15V supply voltage. CMRR is guaranteed down to 6V and there are some typical curves. Output swing with +/-3.3V supply and a 2K or 1K load may be only a few hundred mV worst case, and input voltage range maybe +/-1V.

Frankly, I would likely pick a more appropriate op-amp for this application- you are paying extra for high voltage capability and not using it. You might even want to use regulated +/-2.5V supplies and use a 5.5V op-amp.